# Submit form on ID of RESTful route without persistent object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, rest, routes, resource-id

Rails 3.2.0 | Ruby 1.9.2

Route:

```
xyz_catalog_device_info 
GET|POST /xyz/catalog/devices/:device_id/info(.:format)
xyz/catalog/devices#info`
```

My app wraps up several API services into one system to provide a single place to maintain SSL Certificates and complicated XML generation logic. My controller makes an HTTP call to a 3rd party API to obtain the information, so there's no XYZ::Catalog::Device persisting (no @device) to implement the usual rails form helper tricks.

I want to create a form like the following:

```
%form{ :action => xyz_catalog_device_info_path(:format => :xml) }
  = label_tag :device_id, "Device ID:"
  = text_field_tag :device_id
  = submit_tag "Search"
```

so that it will fill in the device_id in the action.

Is this possible without using javascript? Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like what you are looking for is http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html

Where you would just use soemthing like...

```
= form_tag(xyz_catalog_device_info_path(:format => :xml)) do
  = label_tag :device_id, "Device ID:"
  = text_field_tag :device_id
  = submit_tag "Search"
```

Comment: That's doing pretty much the same thing that I asked for the form. However, I'm trying to submit a form that contains an input field for the resource identifier (device_id) to an action path that also requires that identifier ( /xyz/catalog/devices/:device_id/info.xml ).